# ASP.NET Panels Ignore Style Until Loaded In Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I am working on an application where I want to dynamically load textboxes into panels on page load depending on how many textboxes I need.

I was using javascript/jquery to do this with divs, but I have decided to switch to coding this process to C#. Let me know if that is a bad idea.

**The problem is** that in design view, I have 24 panels, with a class of grid_1 *(I am using the 960 grid system and have 24 columns. I'll never need more than 24 panels so I decided to hard code the panels into the page)*. However, unlike divs, these panels are ignoring styling until they render in the browser.

Here is what they look like in Visual Studio 2012:

[image: The panels stack instead of using the grid styles I applied]

This looks pretty awful because there's 24 of these suckers and it's completely unobvious that it will look right in a web browser.

My code:

```
<div id="myid">
            <div class="container_24" id="myid">
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Should I stop using panels and switch back to javascript and do it all client side or should I keep doing what I'm doing because there's an obvious fix that I'm unaware of and this is perfectly fine coding practice?

-Thanks

Comment: Where in your page do you reference the stylesheet?

Comment: In the header I reference `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/960.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: Ok what about if instead of `<asp:Panel class="..` you try server-side property `<asp:Panel CssClass="..` ?

Comment: That worked! Can you explain why that is?

Comment: Tried to explain in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use server-side `CssClass` server-side property instead of `class` attribute. I.e. Instead of

```
<asp:Panel class="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

Use

```
<asp:Panel CssClass="grid_1 measurementTextBoxContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

This is just a hunch, but I think in this case `class` is treated as generic HTML Element attribute which is processed after entire page has been rendered, while CssClass being server-side property (*tho it still renders as `class` attribute*) takes effect right away